# How do I access a struct nested inside a struct

Tags: swift, struct, nested

I've created a struct with another struct nested inside of it, like this:

```
struct Theme {
    var ID: Int
    var name: String
    struct color {
        var tint: String
        var tintDisabled: String
        var accent: String
        var background: String
        var items: [String]
    }
}
```

I thought I'd be able to address the "tint" item like this:

```
aTheme.color.tint
```

But `aTheme` doesn't have a member `"color"`.

How can I get at it? Or is this just no-go and I should use a different structure?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you've created is a *nested type*—`color` is declared as a type inside the `Theme` type, so to create an instance of `color` you would use this notation:

```
let myColor = Theme.color( ... )
```

I think instead you want a property of a `Theme` instance to be a `color` instance. For this you don't need the types to be nested:

```
struct Color {
    var tint: String
    var tintDisabled: String
    var accent: String
    var background: String
    var items: [String]
}

struct Theme {
    var ID: Int
    var name: String
    var color: Color
}
```

*Note: Types should always be declared with initial caps.*

Comment: Ah, perfect, that makes lots of sense. Of course Theme doesn't know about Color, since basically no one does.

Answer (score 12):

**Updated**: with `Swift 3.1` you can use nested type with `Struct`.

Comment: And what a blessing it is! We can now do what the OP wants. This is great for code organisation, clarity, encapsulation.

Comment: Two years since I asked the question. Woot! It makes so much sense to me, it's hard to understand why it hasn't always been this way.

Comment: You can even private the struct so no one else can use it!

Answer (score 4):

maybe like this?

```
struct Theme {
    var ID: Int
    var name: String  
    var clor = color()
}
struct color {
        var tint: String
        var tintDisabled: String
        var accent: String
        var background: String
        var items: [String]
}
```

then `aTheme.color.tint`

Comment: Just a hair slower. Thank you for the same correct answer.